# AjaxControlToolkit.config file generates error message "AjaxControlToolkit" is not declared

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, configuration-files, bundling-and-minification

Using the AjaxControlToolkit.config file from the ASP.NET Ajax Toolscriptmanager page:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit>
  <controlBundles>
    <controlBundle>
      <control name="AccordionExtender"></control>
      <control name="CalendarExtender"></control>
      <control name="HtmlEditorExtender"></control>
    </controlBundle>
  </controlBundles>
</ajaxControlToolkit>
```

Generates the error message 'AjaxControlToolkit is not declared'. Don't know where or how to declare it.

Comment: Did you look at this http://forums.asp.net/t/1174924.aspx

Comment: @HansDerks: he was asking specifically about the **AjaxControlToolkit.config** file, which isn't mentioned on the page you link to. I'm encountering the same issue as "user2891806"

Comment: I have the same problem. The file is used in the project despite the warning. You can see that when you remove all controls and try to use one on a web form, you will get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

That is just visual studio letting you know it is not defined but it will not affect the functionality. It will work fine assuming you have your AjaxControlToolkit config file in the root directory with your control bundles defined properly

I have that 'error' too but am able to use control bundles just fine in my toolkitscriptmanager; I just ignore the error